# Create new page for component's element in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a problem with joomla. I'm trying to create my fisrt joomla component starting from nothing. I've already been able to create the table mysql, the page form (in the administration section) e the module whose function is print the complete list of the elements.

Anyway I don't get how to create a new page for each element and how to get the dinamic adress.

can you help me to solve this problem by writing me some guide links?

Comment: Please refer to the Joomla documentation. Everything you need to know about components is there and there is even a hello_world component available to download with dummy content

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to MVC and Joomla, I'd **strongly** recommend using [Component Creator](http://component-creator.com/en/).  The free registration lets you create a component with a single table, and it's very fast and easy.  Download the built component and install it, then you can see the parts and pieces you need to make all the magic happen.

Comment: I've used that site to create that component, but how can i create the graphics? Especially how can i create the individual page?

Comment: The page that is "displayed" is in `components\com_yourcomponent\views\yourviewname\tmpl\default.php`.  By default, CC just displays the path to the image that is in the table you created - you need to alter the default.php file to display it as an image instead.  Use the Menu manager to add a new menu item to the component, then just add/edit change from that.